# placeholder vs. data-placeholder, in HTML

Tags: html, placeholder

What's the **difference** between the two?

placeholder vs. data-placeholder?

They both seem to produce the **same results**.

```
<select data-placeholder="Enter name">

<select placeholder="Enter name">
```

What's the difference?

(Which one's stronger?)

Comment: What does “stronger” mean?

Comment: `placeholder` does not work on `<select>` elements, didn't you mean `<input>`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Attribute `placeholder` is a standard HTML5 attribute and `data-placeholder` is just `data-` HTML5 attribute used by some javascript plugin.

Without the external js plugin, `data-placeholder` does nothing while `placeholder` works with the only requirement of having HTML5 support on client browser.

Comment: Actually it is possible to do it without javascript. See https://codepen.io/flesler/pen/AEIFc

Comment: @KorniltsevAnatoly nice solution, but I think it will better after add `not(:focus)` i.e.
`[contenteditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before`

Answer (score 5):

They can't possibly produce the same results. `placeholder` is part of the HTML5 spec to show placeholder text in the field before anything is typed, while `data-*` is just generic data attached to the element.

You might have some JavaScript polyfill or something on the page that uses `data-placeholder`.