# Accessibility using data-placeholder on div element with contentEditable

Tags: accessibility, contenteditable, placeholder, wai-aria

I am styling some placeholder text in a div using data-placeholder attribute and I am wondering if anyone can confirm whether or not this will be accessible?

Comment: This needs a lot more information, including a code example. Is the `<div>` acting as a `<textarea>`? There is no `data-placeholder` attribute, as any attribute preceded by `data-` is custom; assistive technology has no reason to do anything with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709580/placeholder-vs-data-placeholder-in-html

Comment: There is `aria-placeholder` attribute for that, seems, see https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-placeholder